# On matrices satisfying $T^* J T = - J$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, terminology

Let $J\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a fixed matrix and let $T\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix such that
$$
T^* J T = -J
$$
where $T^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $T$.

> Do matrices $T$ satisfying the above property have a name?

On a related note, if $T$ satisfies $T^* J T = J$, then $T$ is commonly referred to as a $J$-unitary matrix (for obvious reasons).

Comment: The reason why $J$-unitary matrices are useful is because they are morphisms, i.e., closed under composition. $T^*JT=-J$ are not closed like this, and the identity does not satisfy this property.

Comment: @Chrystomath: I see. So you are suggesting that matrices satysfying $T^*JT = -J$ are not that useful, so it is likely that they don't have a "standard" name (?).

Comment: I don't know if they're useful or not, but the classes of matrices that have names usually have properties such as being closed under composition, or addition, etc. For example, symmetric, unitary, special linear, symplectic, etc. In this case it's neither. Not even the zero matrix qualifies.

Comment: What is the context that made you consider these type of matrices?

Comment: @KennethGoodenough: I was just studying some results on factorization theory of $J$-unitary matrices and wondered about possible extensions...